# css3 svg animation glitch in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, animation, svg

Here's the site.

http://thevolikov.com/

In Chrome if you go down the page to the blacksmithing orc, look at the anvil. It glitches. If it doesn't, scroll up-down a bit, you will see some black stripes appearing on it from here to there.

I dunno, what it's about. In Firefox and Safari everything's ok.

All the files you can see in Web Inspector/Developer mode.

HTML: index.html.
CSS: zhekaDesignEpta/skills.css

-webkit modifications on properties (animation, transform-origin etc) didn't change anything.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce your problem in Chrome 53 on Win7.

Comment: hmm... maybe it has smth to do with my hardware.
i'm using MacBook Pro 2010, Core 2 Duo, GeForce 320M, macOS Sierra

Comment: my friend also couldn't reproduce it. he said maybe it's something about vertical synchronization